# Task scheduler console application shows just in time debugger on exception preventing program to run again

Tags: exception, console-application, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-task-scheduler

I have a console application that runs every 5 minutes in Windows Task Scheduler. The program doesn't run again if the program is still running after 5 minutes, so only one instance at a time.

However, when an exception occurs, the just in time debugger appears and doesn't go away, preventing the application from running again.

Is there a way to prevent this?  I want the JIT debugger to not appear so the application is finished and it will run again on the next try.

Comment: This is only a "problem" on your machine, it has a JIT-debugger registered.  A goody that came along for the ride when you installed VS on that machine.  With the explicit intention to help you fix your program.  Not an issue on a production machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One question would be why the program is ending with an exception?  Wouldn't it be better to have some redirection into file if you don't need the exception(s).

I would personally disable JIT debugger at registry.  From the [visual studio docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debug-using-the-just-in-time-debugger?view=vs-2019#BKMK_Enabling), when VS is not installed at the computer, which is probably the case.

### Disable Just-In-Time debugging from the Windows registry

Just-In-Time debugging may still be enabled even if Visual Studio is no longer installed on your computer. If Visual Studio is no longer installed, you can disable Just-In-Time debugging by editing the Windows registry.

To **disable Just-In-Time debugging** by editing the registry:

1. From the Windows Start menu, run the Registry Editor (regedit.exe).
2. In the Registry Editor window, locate and **delete** the following registry entries:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\DbgManagedDebugger

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger
   ```
3. If your computer is running a **64-bit** operating system, also **delete** the following registry entries:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\DbgManagedDebugger

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug\Debugger
   ```

Make sure not to delete or change any other registry keys.